# Touchpad isn't working on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo laptop. The touchpad does not work, but a USB mouse does. How can I fix this?

Unfortunately, this command did not change anything. By the way, the output of xinput reads:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So it seems that the touchpad is not even recognized (in contrast to the USB Laser Mouse)

Comment: try `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps` in a terminal.